# Does Meteor 0.8.0 no longer support e.g. {{currentUser.emails.0.address}}?

Tags: meteor

Does Meteor 0.8.0 no longer support e.g. {{currentUser.emails.0.address}}? Can I still do similar inline or do I need a template helper?

Answer (score 10):

It needs bracket notation, e.g. `{{currentUser.emails.[0].address}}`.